# connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge: AFNetworking 3.0

Tags: objective-c, authentication, afnetworking, refresh-token

I have migrated to AFNetworking 3.0 and looking for a way to use Auth Refresh Token

Is there any replacement for:

```
connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:
```